# Eloquent return relationship result instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here in my controller am simply returning everything in a table

```
$data = Model::get();

return response()->json(['data' => $data], 200);
```

I have defined multiple relations in my model

**Relationship1**

```
public function relationship1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(RelatedModel2::class);
}
```

**Relationship2**

```
public function relationship2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(RelatedModel1::class);
}

    ...
```

Is there a simple way to retrieve the actual model relationship instead of the `id` field of the related entry? This is instead of iterating and adding each field I want manually:

```
$data = Model::get();
foreach ($data as $datum) {
    $data->field1 = $datum->relationship1;
    $data->field2 = $datum->relationship2;
    $data->field3 = $datum->relationship3;
}

return response()->json(['data' => $data], 200);
```

Comment: do this $data = Model::all(); hopefully it'll help

Comment: Read about eager loading in Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use function with()

```
return response()->json([
            'data' => Model::with('relation1', 'relation2')->get()
        ]);
```